# php error: Class 'Imagick' not found

Tags: php

I am getting the error "Class 'Imagick' not found".  Somehow I need to make this library accessible to php. I am using Php 5.2.6 on Fedora 8. my php_info has no mention of ImageMagick.

I have tried: yum install ImageMagick and restarted apache, which didn't work.

I also added extension=imagick.ext to my php.ini file and restarted apache, which didn't work.

Comment: Did you search for a image magick php extension ? I imagine that you need something between the C library & your PHP class.

Comment: All my extensions are *.so not *.ext ?

Comment: "didn't work" very good very useful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1726074

For RHEL-based i386 distributions:

```
yum install ImageMagick.i386
yum install ImageMagick-devel.i386
pecl install imagick
echo "extension=imagick.so" > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini
service httpd restart
```

This may also work on other i386 distributions using yum package manager. For x86_64, just replace .i386 with .x86_64

Comment: This is what finally worked for me. I had performed other attemtps which included everything except for the second line. Whatever `yum install ImageMagick-devel.i386` does fixed it for me.

Answer (score 57):

For all to those having problems with this i did this tutorial:

How to install Imagemagick and Php module Imagick on ubuntu?

i did this 7 simple steps:

**Update libraries, and packages**

```
apt-get update
```

**Remove obsolete things**

```
apt-get autoremove
```

**For the libraries of ImageMagick**

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

**for the core class Imagick**

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

**For create the binaries, and conections in beetween**

```
pecl install imagick
```

**Append the extension to your `php.ini`**

```
echo "extension=imagick.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

**Restart Apache**

```
service apache2 restart
```

---

I found a problem. PHP searches for .so files in a folder called /usr/lib/php5/20100525, and the imagick.so is stored in a folder called /usr/lib/php5/20090626. So you have to copy the file to that folder.

Comment: The question as written specifies Fedora.  I'd suggest adding something about whether these steps for Ubuntu are also likely to work on Fedora, or which bits might have to be modified.

Comment: Bit worried about step 6. Do you really want to clobber php.ini? Or should that be ">>" for appending?

Comment: I had to `apt-get install php5-dev php-pear` in order to complete the steps on Debian Wheezy

Comment: This didn't help with command line imagemagick on Ubuntu. The Ubuntu answer below works. None of the many things listed in this answer helped, seems like it loads every library except the right one!

Comment: For me with php7.0-fpm the following command is enough to install and enable imagick: `sudo apt-get install php-imagick`

Comment: Just make sure to add php version with the package otherwise it will always install the latest version of this package.  For php 7.4 it should be - apt-get install php7.4-imagick

Answer (score 12):

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev pecl imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
sudo pecl install imagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Some dependencies will probably already be met but excluding the Apache service, that's everything required for PHP to use the `Imagick` class.

Comment: `Unable to locate package pecl`

Answer (score 10):

**For MAMP running on Mac OSX**

Find out the what version of PHP and install the right version via brew

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-imagick
```

Add the extension by modifying the php.ini template in MAMP

[image]

Verify the Imagick

[image]

Comment: for **php 7.0** => `brew install php70-imagick` 

**php 7.1** => `brew install php71-imagick`

_Restart Service_ : `sudo brew services restart php70`

Answer (score 6):

**Debian 9**

I just did the following and everything else needed got automatically installed as well.

```
sudo apt-get -y -f install php-imagick
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: With PHP7 : 
    sudo apt-get install php7.0-imagick -y
    service apache2 restart

Answer (score 5):

Install Imagic in PHP7:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

Comment: In my case, I then had to run `service php7.3-fpm restart` and provide `vagrant` as the password.

Answer (score 1):

On an EC2 at AWS, I did this:

```
 yum list | grep imagick
```

Then found a list of ones I could install...

```
 php -v
```

told me which version of php I had and thus which version of imagick

```
yum install php56-pecl-imagick.x86_64
```

Did the trick. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Docker container installation for `php:XXX` Debian based images:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmagickwand-dev
RUN pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* || true
```

Answer (score 0):

imagick become not supported in <= php7.0
the Ideal Solution is alternative Package Please find this here
https://github.com/DantSu/php-image-editor

Answer (score 0):

#### Install Base Imagick Repos

Many of these answers are great, if you are using PHP5, but PHP8 offers too many features to just pass up, and imagick is a bit different here.

Install the base imagick repos:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-imagick php8.1-imagick imagemagick php-imagick php-pear php-dev
```

#### Install Imagick's Extension into PHP

You may want to omit `php8.1-imagick` if you are not up to version 8.1 yet. `php-pear` is where the `pecl` command lives, so, if that doesn't install correctly, you'll get an error when you need to do the next command...

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

#### Update PHP.ini

Find your `php.ini` file with...

```
php -i | grep  -i php.ini
```

You may get output like...

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
```

Open this file and add to the end of the file this text: `extension=imagick.so`.

#### Restart PHP

Then restart your server.  Any of these will do:

```
systemctl restart apache2
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

#### Check if the Install Worked

- See the results of `phpinfo()` on a web page, which should mention imagick.
- See the results of simulated `phpinfo()` info calls from the command line with  `php -r "echo phpinfo();" | grep 'imagick';`.
- See the internal storage of `phpinfo()` from the command line with `php -i | grep 'imagick'`.
- See the installed packages containing `imagick` in the name with `dpkg --list | grep 'imagick'`.

Note: These are all important, because while I was debugging, I was able to see Imagick installed at lower layers (i.e. with `dpkg`), but was not seeing it in the higher layers (i.e. with `phpinfo();` through webhost).  Cheers.