# How to install Image Magick for MAMP (Pro) on Mountain Lion (10.8.2)

Tags: imagemagick, mamp, osx-mountain-lion

I've been searching for a way to install Image Magick on my Mountain Lion setup (where I use MAMP Pro). I did find [this article](http://www.adamstacey.co.uk/2010/06/28/installing-image-magick-and-imagick-for-php-for-mamp/), but it isn't specific to ML. Also found a couple other similar questions here on SO but they were too specific I think. Doesn't help that I'm not great at this sort of thing. Can anyone point me to a good resource?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Make sure you check out Joel Farris' answer if you're using an up-to-date version of MAMP**

---

I finally managed to get it installed properly using Homebrew and the instructions here: http://egoco.de/post/23167969231/installing-imagemagick-for-php-and-mamp

I did have to run brew doctor and brew link a couple of times to fix dependencies (and change permissions on a file or two), and use

```
brew install php54-imagick
```

rather than the one mentioned at the url.

The extension he mentions at the end (the bit you have to paste in your different ini files) is:

```
[imagick]
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-imagick/3.1.0RC2/imagick.so"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had to run this before running the above `brew tap josegonzalez/php` `brew tap homebrew/dupes` as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/16064860/778669

Comment: apparently the latest mamp pro version comes with imagemagick pre-installed, Check http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/

Comment: I had to run `brew update` and clean up the whole thing before running `brew install php55-imagick`

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I was failing on instruction by egoco.de, but your two lines of code fixed everything ;) Cheers!

Comment: if imagick is preinstalled on mamp then why can't i use it. i also use bluehost and it says it's supposed to be preinstalled as well but it still says not found. can someone PLEASE help me with this. it's driving me nuts

Answer (score 48):

As was pointed out in [erwinheiser's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201071/how-to-install-image-magick-for-mamp-pro-on-mountain-lion-10-8-2#comment34751997_15023091), MAMP 3 now **comes with imagemagick pre-installed**. I checked [MAMP's User Guide (PDF)](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/MAMP-PRO-3-User-Guide.pdf) and found this:

> The ImageMagick PHP module is included by default, but you must enable it inside the php.ini template file. Remove the ‘;’ from the following line.
>
> `;extension=imagick.so`

And how do you find and change the (right) **php.ini** file for MAMP Pro?

- From MAMP's menu choose **File** › **Edit Template** › **PHP** › [the latest version]

  - *or* use the keyboard shortcut: **⌘4**
- Make the edit. (Imagick was was at line 542 in mine.)
- Save and close the file.
- MAMP asks if you want to restart the servers now, choose **yes**.

And you're done!

Comment: After doing this, I get "Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat" while trying to create a thumbnail.

Comment: This may have to do with the file extension of your image. Are you trying it with a '.jpg'?

Comment: Tried with both a jpg and a png, same error. Finally I'm trying with exec() or passthrough(), because the sytem-installed binary works ok, until I find a way that imagick reads those.

Comment: If you don't have MAMP Pro, depending on your PHP version look here in OSX: **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini** then just create an alias in your .bash_profile and easily edit your php.ini file whenever you need to: **alias phpini='nano /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini'**

Comment: After losing a lot of time, this is for me the best answer for install ImageMagick for MAMP 3.4 on 2015..

Comment: Note that PHP 7 in MAMP 3.5 does not have the ImageMagick extension installed. So uncommenting it in the php.ini file won't have any effect there.

Answer (score 6):

MAMP comes with Imagick installed. I have MAMP v3.2.1 (not MAMP Pro) running on OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite).

I enabled imagick by editing php.ini file which comes with MAMP.

php.ini file is available on the following path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/conf/php.ini
```

Replace 5.6.7 with your php version number.

php.ini file will contain the following line:

```
;extension=imagick.so
```

Change that line to:

```
extension=imagick.so
```

Now restart the MAMP servers and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

We made a Mac installer package here— http://www.cactuslab.com/imagemagick/

Comment: Nice. Well, now I know if I ever need it again. :)

Comment: I just tried to use that and got "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.)"

Comment: this installer is for ImageMagick only or also for the Imagick php extension?

Comment: Seems not to include the php extension.