# Laravel 4 - ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php, imagemagick

trying to get ImageMagick working on my local machine but receive the error:

```
ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.
```

I have never seen that error so not sure where to go from here. I am running PHP 5.6.2 (according to MAMP) and have since I first saw the error installed ImageMagick with homebrew and then also tried the mac installer but I still get the same issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, using homestead, apt and nginx:

1. Log into homestead
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick php5-imagick && sudo service php5-fpm restart`

   - `sudo apt-get update` - make sure everything is up to date.
   - `sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick php5-imagick` - make sure the modules are installed. Since the question is about PHP5 this is also using `php5-imagick`, I guess there is a newer version available. They `-y` part is just about automatically answering `Yes` to any questions from the install.
   - `sudo service php5-fpm restart` - after installing a new php module it's needed to reload the service using that. In this case, since the question is about MAMP, I assume they're trying to run something with a webserver, therefore it's about the `php-fpm` service.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I'm getting an error with this: Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Answer (score 2):

I realise it's been a while since you asked the question, however I ran into this issue also. In my case (using HomeBrew) I simply installed ImageMagick AND the PHP module using:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install php55-imagick
apachectl restart
```

It's important to restart APACHE after installing these.

As far as your question is concerned (MAMP), There are many instructions online on how to install ImageMagick with MAMP, see: [How to install Image Magick for MAMP (Pro) on Mountain Lion (10.8.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201071/how-to-install-image-magick-for-mamp-pro-on-mountain-lion-10-8-2)

As one of the comments suggests, ImageMagick comes with MAMP, you just have to enable it.

Hope this helps someone :)