# C Compile Fatal Error 'file not found' from ImageMagick Install Mac OS

Tags: c, macos, imagemagick

I am trying to compile a C program that requires Image Magick's MagickWand.h:

```
#include "wand/MagickWand.h"
```

But my Image Magick was installed through Homebrew on my Mac so I changed the include to the actual location:

```
#include </usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h>
```

However, when I compiled the program I received the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h:71:10: fatal error: 'wand/method-attribute.h' file not found
#include "wand/method-attribute.h"
```

Now I've been going into the .h files when this error crops up and changing their #includes so that they are pointed correctly (because that appears to be the problem), but there is always a new error here and I'd rather not spend hours manually updating these because of a Homebrew install.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this without manually updating each file?  I'm not sure exactly what the problem is so perhaps there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is this a related question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16723546/814416

Comment: It's not because they were referring to a different build and the ImageMagick site only has a complex and lengthy (actually over my head) explanation of how to manually install it on mac os.  I was hoping for a simpler solution than uninstalling in Homebrew and re-installing manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should include the *MagickWand* library as system headers, and keep the generic path. This will keep your future compiling from breaking when the system/library updates.

```c
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>
```

Tell your C compiler where homebrew installed ImageMagick by setting the preprocessor include flag `-I`, and linking/library options with the `-L` & `-l` flags.

*example:*

```sh
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/include/ImageMagick-6 \
      myProject.c -o myProject.o \
      -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/lib \
      -lMagickWand-6.Q16 \
      -lMagickCore-6.Q1
```

To simplify the whole process, ImageMagick ships `MagickWand-config` utility. This will take care of libs, includes, and definitions for you.

*example:*

```sh
CFLAGS=$(MagickWand-config --cflags)
LFLAGS=$(MagickWand-config --libs)
clang $CFLAGS myProject.c -o myProject.o $LFLAGS
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and suggesting the MagickWand utility.  Worked very simply and have a better understanding of whats going on.