# error class imagick- xampp mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, imagick

I got this:

1. PHP Version 5.6.30
2. Apache Version  Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
3. Mac OSX El Capitan

Does anyone know how to load this class?

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/polygon.php on line 7

I need work with imagick.

Comment: Xampp only bundle Image GD i believe, you have to [install Imagic](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php) (php plugin) separately..

Comment: https://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0.tar.gz cannot download file for http

Comment: hmm, tried to [follow this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866547/4648586). I never touch mac before, but people says its looked like *nixes.