# Image Magick on OpenSUSE: Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

Tags: php, apache2, imagick, opensuse

To be short:
OpenSUSE 13.1, php5, apache2, ImageMagick-6.8.6.9-2.28.1.x86_64.
When I call class Imagick I got respond:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found...

I've googled for the solution but nothing helped. All soultions were for some other Linux distribution, none for OpenSUSE.
I've tried to find this imagick.so on my computer, but without any result. Seems that it doesn't exists although ImageMagick is installed with tons of .so files. And there's no .so from ImageMagick in php5/extensions.
Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [php error: Class 'Imagick' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790191/php-error-class-imagick-not-found)

Comment: Do not understand.....

Comment: Felix, it only looks like duplicated, but it is not. I asked for solution on OpenSUSE, all other questions about ImageMagick were for some other Linux distribution. I've tried to adjust those solutions for OpenSUSE, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the code you used to install imagick then?

Comment: It seems it came with OpenSUSE cause I didn't istall it. Some other services use it I guess, like GIMP. There is a folder /usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.8.6 with lot of .so files. When I tried to install ImageMagick with zypper it responded that there's nothing to do cause  ImageMagick-6.8.6.9-2.28.1.x86_64 is already installed.